# How to access the next iteration of a for loop

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, dictionary

I have dictionary which I'm looping through. I want to say that if a value == a certain number (0 in this case) then the value of the next iteration of the for loop will be 2x that value.

I have a dictionary like the following:

```
d = {'a' : 1, 'b' : 0, 'c' : 4}
```

When I loop through the dictionaries with a for loop I'd like to multiply the next iteration by 2 if the current iteration = 0.

```
for k, v in d.items():
    if k == 0:
        [next iteration v = v * 2]
    else:
        v = v + 1
```

So I would expect to end up with a dictionary like this:

```
d = {'a' : 2, 'b' : 0, 'c' : 9}
```

This is just a simple example but hopefully illustrates what I'm trying to achieve.

Thanks

Comment: The problem is, you are using dictionary and it doesn't keep its order so you'll most likely get different values for different runs.

Comment: Do you know of another way I could achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [orderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) to have a dictionary and keep your order.

Looking at your algorithm, you are adding 1 to all values if it is not zero and if it is zero, you multiply the next item first, then add 1 to it. One of the basic and easiest way is, having a flag to decide if you should multiply the next value or not.

```
import collections

d = (("a", 1), ("b", 0), ("c", 4))
od = collections.OrderedDict(d)

multiply = False
for k in od.keys():
    if multiply:
        od[k] *= 2
    if od[k] != 0:
        od[k] += 1
        multiply = False
    else:
        multiply = True

print(od)
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you are using a dictionary, dictionaries do not keep there order.  You would ave to use something such as a list.  Not sure ho you would set key/value pairs in a list though.